# Google analytics - cohort breakdown by custom user property issue (not set)

Tags: google-analytics

I am having trouble with the cohort analysis in a Google Analytics App + Web Property, where we have custom user properties set up for our web and mobile apps.

I would like to see a breakdown of users in the cohort, by one of the custom user properties that my app and website reports to analytics.
My issue is, that if I choose this custom property for the cohort breakdown, and set the inclusion to "first touch", new users from mobile app will not be shown in the breakdown by the property but will be shown in the "not set" row.

Could you guys help, what are we doing wrong?